# Roxy Fileman remove part of URL in returnurl

Tags: javascript, php, roxy-fileman

I'm attempting to get Roxy Fileman to work in my environment, however running into a little hitch. I can see the directories for images (done via a symlink) however when returning from the Roxy UI via the "select" button I'm getting a url like this:

https://images.example.com/path/to/Uploads/symlink/123/logo.png

And what I really want is:

https://images.example.com/symlink/123/logo.png

I've already put in the RETURN_URL_PREFIX, however I'm still getting the extended path whether I use a session_path_key or just the regular root (and then browse to the correct directory via the symlink).

My code for the session_path_key looks like:

```
<?php $_SESSION['dynamic-user-folder'] = "/path/to/Uploads/symlink/"; ?>
```

and my config.json:

```
"FILES_ROOT":          "",
"RETURN_URL_PREFIX":   "https://images.example.com/",
"SESSION_PATH_KEY":    "dynamic-user-folder",
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the answer. In the plugin php folder there is a file called filelist.php. In here I simply added a

```
$fullPath = str_replace('/path/to/Uploads/', '', $fullPath);
```

And this returns the path variable p with all of the stuff I don't want removed back to the UI, so when you do a select it uses the correct URL with the RETURN_URL_PREFIX in front and then the symlink and file name.